# Cmake Ctest mixed logs

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm running my tests with --parallel "${JOBS_NUM} (this depends on the system), everything works fine except logs of tested applications - they are mixed, as a result, it's hard to read:

example of my tests:

test 1: started

logs from test2...

....

test 1: finished

I've found this comment [[CMake] parallel ctest spawning too many threads](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-April/043967.html) , but looks like it's still not resolved.

I've checked ctest documentation but can't any options to disable output buffering, or some kind of mutex. Is it possible to do it in cmake ctest?
I would like to the the next:

test1: started:

test1: logs

test1: finished

test2: started

test2: logs

test2: finished

while all tests are running in parallel.

Comment: cant you force it to use one thread?

Comment: yes, without -parallel  option it works in a single thread. Everything works fine. 

Multi threads is needed to decrease time of test on CI.

Comment: if you need them to run in order you should use single thread, you have to trade off between speed and running in order